# this.state.query isn't set even after this.setState({query:value}) call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which contains the handler function for when a user inserts something into a text box. When this is done, the `query` field in the state object should be set to the value of the text box.

For example, if the text box is empty, and then the user inputs "s", in `handleInput()`, I will do `this.setState({event.target.value})`, which should set `this.state.query` to "s". But this doesn't work.

When I input "s", the line `alert("setting query to "+this.state.query);` shows me `"setting query to"`, instead of the expected `"setting query to s"`. This is really strange to me, because the line `alert(event.target.value)` prints out "s", so the value is definitely in `event.target.value`.

Then if I input another character, say "a", the alert shows me "setting query to s". It's as if `this.state.query` is lagging behind by 1 character all the time. Here's the code:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let today = new Date();
    this.state = {
      searchSuggestion: 'Search for tweets here',
      anchorEl: null,
      date: today.toJSON(),
      geocode: undefined,
      page: 0,
      placeName: 'the World',
      query: ''
    }
    // Defining debounce is needed in constructor 
    this.searchTweets = debounce(500, this.searchTweets);
    this.searchGeocode = debounce(500, this.searchGeocode);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    modelInstance.addObserver(this);
  }

  handleInput = event => {
    alert("Handling input");
    let query = event.target.value;
    alert(event.target.value); // "s"
    this.setState({
      query: event.target.value
    });
    alert("setting query to "+this.state.query); // outputs "setting query to". this.state.query isn't set to anything!
    let until = new Date(this.state.date);
    this.searchTweets(query, this.state.geocode, until);
  }

  // Searches tweets until date
  searchTweets = (query, location, date) => {
    this.props.handleStatusChange('INITIAL');
    modelInstance.searchTweets(query, location, date).then(result => {
      modelInstance.setTweets(result);
      this.props.handleStatusChange('LOADED');
      this.setState({
        data: result
      });
    }).catch(() => {
      this.props.handleStatusChange('ERROR');
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div className='search'>
          <Row id='searchInput'>
            <SearchInput handleInput={this.handleInput.bind(this)} searchInput={this.state.searchInput} searchSuggestion={this.state.searchSuggestion} page={1}/>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <SearchNav page={this.state.page}/>
          </Row>
          <Row id='date-location'>
            <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2} className='text'>
              <p>UNTIL</p>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4} className='date'>
              <SearchDate date={this.state.date} anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl} click={this.handleClick} dayChange={this.onDayChange}/>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2} className='text'>
              <p>IN</p>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4} className='location'>
              <SearchLocation placeName = {this.state.placeName} handleLocation={this.handleLocation.bind(this)}/>
            </Col>

          </Row>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Search;
```

How come this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

It says *"`this.props` and `this.state` **may** be updated asynchronously"* but it should almost say **will** be, the update is currently always asynchronous, it just may or may not be batched.

If you need to do something only after `this.state` has been updated, use the [second argument](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), which is a callback for when the update has been made.

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback of setState instead, which has the updated value of `this.state`:

```
this.setState({
  query: event.target.value
}, () => alert(this.state.query));
```